# Python: How to track two or more equal variables in a while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to count the amount of names that follow the first name in a line of a .txt file to determine who has the most names after them using python using the following code:

```
lines=0
wordCount=0
mostWordsInLine = 0
follows = open("follows.txt", "r")


for word in follows:
    lines += 1
    f1=word.split()
    wordCount=wordCount+len(f1)
    if len(f1) > mostWordsInLine:
        mostWordsInLine = len(f1)
        mostWordsInLine = word[: word.find(' ')]

print ("Most social user: " + str(mostWordsInLine))
```

The .txt file looks like this:

```
andrew fred
fred
judy andrew fred
george judy andrew
john george
```

And the output I get is:

```
Most social user: andrew
```

My issue is that my code should return judy and george but instead returns andrew for some reason. How can I fix this?

Comment: You are assigning two different values to `mostWordsInLine`.  The second one, a string, makes no sense when compared to a number on the next iteration of the loop.  You need two different variables here, one for the count and one for the name.

Comment: Can you elaborate your question? it is not clear.

Comment: hint: use readline() method to iterate over the lines

Comment: @kraymer Looping over the file object works just fine for that as well.

Comment: You tagged the question Python 3... is it actually Python 2? That's the only way this code actually produced the output you claim.

Comment: Related, if not a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50480555/count-number-of-words-from-file-separated-by-each-line-and-return-highest-numb#50480682

Answer (score 0):

```
wordCount=0
mostWordsInLine = 0
follows = open("follows.txt", "r")
mostFollows = []


for word in follows:
    f1=word.split()
    wordCount += len(f1)
    if len(f1) > mostWordsInLine:
        mostWordsInLine = len(f1)
        mostFollows = [f1[0]]
    elif len(f1) == mostWordsInLine:
        mostFollows.append(f1[0])


print ("Most social user: " + ''.join(mostFollows))
```

Comment: Close, but you're not handling `mostFollows` right. You need to only append to it if the length is _equal_ to the highest, and clear it if the highest length increases.

Comment: thanks for your help! unfortunately I tried running your code and I got george and john instead of judy and george, any ideas why this still isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Not giving a direct answer to homework, but a technique you can use to solve this and future problems you may face: add `print` statements to your code to understand what is happening.  For example, if we add the 2 print statements below:

```
for word in follows:
    lines += 1
    f1=word.split()
    wordCount=wordCount+len(f1)
    print("f1 = {}, mostWordsInLine = {}".format(f1, mostWordsInLine))
    if len(f1) > mostWordsInLine:
        mostWordsInLine = len(f1)
        mostWordsInLine = word[: word.find(' ')]
    print("    after comparison: mostWordsInLine = {}".format(mostWordsInLine))
```

It will print the following output:

```
f1 = ['andrew', 'fred'], mostWordsInLine = 0
    after comparison: mostWordsInLine = andrew
f1 = ['fred'], mostWordsInLine = andrew
    after comparison: mostWordsInLine = andrew
f1 = ['judy', 'andrew', 'fred'], mostWordsInLine = andrew
    after comparison: mostWordsInLine = andrew
f1 = ['george', 'judy', 'andrew'], mostWordsInLine = andrew
    after comparison: mostWordsInLine = andrew
f1 = ['john', 'george'], mostWordsInLine = andrew
    after comparison: mostWordsInLine = andrew
f1 = [], mostWordsInLine = andrew
    after comparison: mostWordsInLine = andrew
Most social user: andrew
```

The first time one of the output lines does not make sense, see if you can figure out why.

Comment: Are you using Python 2? Comparing an int to a str raises an exception in Python 3.

Comment: Yes; this was Python 2. I assume the OP is also using Python 2, since it worked for him too.

Comment: Just noticed the Python 3 tag though...hmm

Answer (score -1):

The string library has a .count('name') function.  So you could count each element in the for loop and compare them all.  You need to clarify the problem because andrew and fred occur three times.

"Makes sense....First have a list of unique names [names]. Then use a dictionary to store them. {name:[list_names] then len(string) . Write a function that iterates the dictionary and retrieves the dictionary with the most speakers."

Comment: its a bit confusing but "who has the most names after them", so i think its "name [follower] ... " so you see who has the most followers

Comment: Makes sense....First have a list of unique names [names]. Then use a dictionary to store them. {name:[list_names] then len(string) .  Write a function that iterates the dictionary and retrieves the dictionary with the most speakers.