# Count number of words from file, separated by each line, and return highest number

Tags: python, string, file, count

Using a dummy file (`followst.txt`) with the following contents:

```
andrew fred  
fred  
judy andrew fred  
george judy andrew  
john george
```

The first name of each line represents the user, whilst any names after it represent users that they follow. I need to be able to count how many people each person follows and then return the highest number. In this case it would return:

```
george
judy
```

However I'm having trouble figuring out how to count each line separately. I'm currently doing this:

```
fhand=open('followst.txt', 'r')
inp=fhand.read()
str= inp
words= str.split()
number_of_words=len(words)
print(number_of_words-1)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468839/python-how-to-track-two-or-more-equal-variables-in-a-while-loop (same assignment?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
with open('followst.txt') as afile:
    lines = afile.readlines()
follow_dict = {}
max_follower = 0

for line in lines:
    names = line.split()
    follow_dict[names[0]] = len(names)-1
    if max_follower < len(names)-1:
        max_follower = len(names)-1

for name,num_of_follower in follow_dict.items():
    if num_of_follower == max_follower:
        print(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `readlines`

```
fhand=open('Test.txt', 'r')
inp=fhand.readlines()
words= [str1.split() for str1 in inp]
number_of_words=[len(word)-1 for word in words]
print(number_of_words)
m = max(number_of_words)
ids = [i for i, j in enumerate(number_of_words) if j == m]
print([word[0] for word in [words[i] for i in ids]])
```

This will return

> [1, 0, 2, 2, 1]
>
> ['judy', 'george']